# Delete multiple records. Loop in loop in a procedure

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a procedure which compiles successfully.It updates the docmeta table and inserts into updatehistory table after the records flows into temp_pay_term table.The problem is code requires two fixes 1) when  their are multiple records in temp_pay_term table, delete command at line 65 in below code, deletes only one record of the temp_term table and not all. I want to delete all records of temp_pay_term table once this procedure completes its full work. Will i have to use loop within loop to achieve this. if yes, then how?? please show me the code.
2) this is bothering me for some time now. from line 28-34 in below code, when i update docmeta table to set XPAYMENTTERM value,since the condition thereafter is a subquery, so i can get only one row. For this reason i want to return record wher pid   = d.xProject_id AND rownum <= 1 order by paytermtimestamp desc. but order by clause does not applies here and throws an error. How can apply order by clause here to get the latest record.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
PROCEDURE TERMUPDATE
IS
  RecordCount    INT;
  varDID         NUMBER(38);
  varpaymentterm VARCHAR2(200 CHAR);
  varprojectID   VARCHAR2(30 CHAR);
BEGIN
  RecordCount :=0;
  SELECT COUNT(1)
  INTO RecordCount
  FROM temp_pay_term;
  IF RecordCount > 0 THEN
    FOR X       IN
    (SELECT DISTINCT r.ddocName
    FROM temp_Pay_Term p,
      docMeta d,
      revisions r
    WHERE TO_CHAR(p.pid) = d.xproject_id
    AND r.did            = d.did
    )
    LOOP
      SELECT MAX(did)
      INTO varDid
      FROM revisions r
      WHERE r.ddocname = X.ddocName
      GROUP BY r.ddocname;
      UPDATE docmeta d
      SET XPAYMENTTERM =
        (SELECT paymentterm
        FROM temp_pay_term
        WHERE pid   = d.xProject_id
        AND rownum <= 1
        )
      WHERE d.did = vardid returning xpaymentterm,
        xProject_id
      INTO varpaymentterm,
        varprojectID;
      INSERT
      INTO updatehistory
        (
          UPDATEID,
          DID,
          UPDATETIME,
          METADATAFIELD,
          NEWVALUE,
          OLDVALUE,
          UPDATEDBY
        )
        VALUES
        (
          (SELECT MAX(updateid)+1 FROM updatehistory
          )
          ,
          (SELECT did FROM revisions WHERE did = vardid
          ),
          systimestamp,
          'Payment term',
          varpaymentterm,
          ( SELECT oldpaymentterm FROM temp_pay_term WHERE pid = varprojectID
          ),
          'sysadmin'
        );
    END LOOP;
    DELETE FROM temp_Pay_Term WHERE pid = varprojectID;
    COMMIT;
  END IF;
END TERMUPDATE; -- PL SQL code
```

Comment: You could delete all records from the table by removing the `WHERE` clause, but that's a problem because there may still be unprocessed rows (note `varprojectID` is passed as a parameter!).  This procedure isn't multi-process safe - either you lock the entire table, or risk `MAX(updateid)` returning incorrect values.  `updateId` should probably by autogenerated, and you probably want to separate the history function to a trigger anyways.  If you can post sample source and destination tables/data we can probably point you in a better direction than this - avoid loops in SQL if possible.

Comment: The source of temp_pay_term table is a staging table and gets data via a trigger.below format of temp_pay_term table.updateid is the  id of the last record saved in updatehistory table and just adds a value to it .PID  PAYMENTTERM PAYTERMTIMESTAMP     OLDPAYMENTTERM  
919191 30 NET  09-FEB-14 06.11.10.000000000 AM  NET 120
919191 NET 45  17-FEB-14 05.31.08.535475000 AM  NET 60
117175 NET 60  17-FEB-14 05.31.08.834264000 AM  NET 120

Comment: That should have been added to the question, and you need the _source_ tables too (`docmeta`, `revisions`, etc).  I'm fairly convinced this can be turned into something that'll perform better and be **SAFER**, but we need a look at the larger picture.  There are several flaws with the current approach - it's not something I would have allowed to pass a code review; however we need more info to be able to give better advice.

Comment: Thanks Clockwork. with some of your guidance and some of my wit, i figured out solution for Problem 1. but Problm 2 still remains. from line 28-34 in below code, when i update docmeta table to set XPAYMENTTERM value,since the condition thereafter is a subquery, so i can get only one row. For this reason i want to return record wher pid = d.xProject_id AND rownum <= 1 order by paytermtimestamp desc. but order by clause does not applies here and throws an error. How can I apply order by clause here to get the latest record?

Comment: First, update your code with your latest effort.  'Throws an error' is not a valid problem description - be specific.  Which error?  My guess is either that `rownum` doesn't exist, or you're getting more than one row.  I still think this should be re-written to be safer and faster.